# admin panel - How to remove "delete" button from category editing page

Tags: php, categories, css, admin

i want to disable, hide or remove delete buttons from category page

[image]

I tried editing functions.php with no luck:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');

function hide_category_buttons() {
  echo '<style>
    .taxonomy-category tr:hover .row-actions {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: You might do better removing the delete_terms capability from the users you want to hide the button from.

Comment: Right, Hiding admin UI options with CSS is a hacky solution, and while it's not such an easy method, using WP Roles and Caps is the technically right way to go - https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Answer (score 0):

There is some modification in your code, insted of this class `.taxonomy-category tr:hover .row-actions` apply css on this class `.taxonomy-category .row-actions span.delete`, it willl work.

Here is whole code.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');

function hide_category_buttons() {
   echo '<style>
     .taxonomy-category .row-actions span.delete {
        visibility: hidden;
     }
   </style>';
}
```

Comment: It's not working, but is it the right place to put this code in functions.php of my theme if im modifying admin panel, should this code go some where else?

Comment: Have you try with my code ? It's working correctly. function.php file is right place to put this code.

Comment: For some reason it's not working even with your code :(

Comment: Yes, I see that. For twentyseventeen theme it's working and for other themes it's not working.

Comment: I'm using oceanwp, do you have any ideas?

Comment: But what could be the problem tho :(?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your CSS selector is wrong.
You can filter the admin pages where your function runs and you can use an universal selector.

```
global $pagenow;   
 
if (( $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' ) && ($_GET['taxonomy'] == 'product_cat') && 
($_GET['post_type'] == 'product') ) {
    add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons'); 
}

function hide_category_buttons() {
  echo '<style> .row-actions > .delete { display: none; }  </style>';
}
```

Comment: How does that target the 'delete' button specifically?

Comment: Oh, thought we need to remove all of the buttons.
Use this to target the delete button: 
<style> .row-actions > .delete { display: none; }  </style>

Comment: That works, thanks!!

Comment: Can you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a filter for action links.

```
apply_filters( "{$taxonomy}_row_actions", $actions, $tag );
```

For product_cat taxonomy:

```
add_filter('product_cat_row_actions', function($actions, $term) {
    unset($actions['delete']);
    return $actions;
});
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_row_actions/